# How to find CSS related to specific page?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way  to find which CSS tags and elements are related to the specific HTML page section?

For example: We have a large CSS file but few of elements are related to content in HTML classes, is there any way to find related elements and remove other parts?

Comment: In Chrome -> Right click on the element -> Inspect -> See the style linked to it (Right hand side). https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/?hl=en

Comment: There are many, many libraries and tools which do this. Search harder.

Comment: I know this, I did, but there are many other elements which are related to that section and I can't find one by one through chrome inspect, that's why I was thinking maybe there's a software to find this.

Answer (score 1):

How large is the CSS file? I can't think of anything else than splitting it to multiple *libraries* and then including a library in your page if it's required.

For example, if the page has a slider then it will have a CSS link to `slider.css` this might not be ideal when you send too many `HTTP` requests so you might embed the *library* as internal `<style>` CSS. I've seen many WordPress theme developers use that technique.

This shouldn't be a problem since **minification** and **Gzipping** reduce the filesize drastically and once the file is **cached** your users wouldn't need to wait extra time to load your next pages.

Answer (score 1):

### For Chrome

In the [**Chrome DevTools**](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), there is an Audits tab that will allow you to run a Web Page Performance audit and see a list of unused CSS rules :

[image]

---

### For Firefox

You could install one of these add-ons :

- [**CSS Usage**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10704/) for [**Firebug**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/?src=search)
- [**Dust-Me Selectors**](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/?src=external-brothercake)

[image]

*CSS Usage*

[image]

*Dust-Me Selectors*

Comment: @Reddy : I added an option for Chrome

Comment: @Reddy : I knew that... but judging by your comment, I guess it wasn't obvious... which is why I added more info + an option for Chrome. So thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is. It would be really hard to do this, too, because your system could build up a page by including 500 different files of different languages. How could such a program know which of your files is included where and under which conditions?

The thing that I think comes closest would be using your DevTools to see which styles apply to which element and maybe by hand or in an automated way create a list of which CSS rules apply to which end-page (for example which URL endpoint) element. But! Even then it would be hard, because it would be really hard for a program to find out which styles are dynamically added to elements (for example Javascript could add/remove classes when a user performs a certain action).

Comment: Yes you are right, it's really hard, that's why I thought maybe there's a program can do this easier. thanks for your reply